# Find highest number from a group of numbers in a div

Tags: javascript

I have a set of numbers like this in a div: `<div id="numbers">1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10</div>`

How can I find the highest number from that group and display it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```js
// get the numbers that are contained in your div
var numbers = document.getElementById("numbers").innerHTML;

// split the string you have read and create an array of numbers
var array = numbers.split(',').map(function(number){ return parseFloat(number)});

// sort that array
array = array.sort(function(a,b){ return b-a;});

   // return the first element, which would be the highest.
alert("The greatest number is "+array[0]);
```

```html
<div id="numbers">1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,105.20,110.85</div>
```

Comment: it returns with this "The greatest number is NaN"

Comment: If your run this snippet you will get 10, please, click on run code snippet.

Comment: it works but i forgot to mention some of the numbers have . in, for example 105.20, 110.85 and the . isnt coming out, it will display 110 instead of 110.85

Comment: @j8730 then you have to parse your numbers as floats, in order to take into account the decimal part. Please try the updated code. (where we had parseInt we have parseFloat.

Comment: @j8730 you are welcome :) ! I am glad that I helped.

Answer (score 4):

```js
//read content of div
var list = document.getElementById("numbers").innerText;
//split it into an array of numbers
list = list.split(",");
//get the biggest element
var max = Math.max.apply(null, list);
//ta-daaaa
document.write("The max is: " + max);
```

```html
<div id="numbers">1,2,3,4,5,6,131,23,99,8,15</div>
```

That ought to do it.

Comment: You have (+1) from me, nice script.

Comment: it doesnt return anything?

Comment: No, it simply prints out the max value. This exists as a demo of an algorithm. Itd be up to you to utilize it, or move it into a function so it can return, etc.